# Laravel Input Merge with Model Value

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Having problems with filling inputs with values i get from a query.

```
$fieldData = myModel::where('id', '=', '5')->first();
//Here's not working properly :
Input::merge(array('inputName' => $fieldData->name));

$variableBag = \Input::all();
```

and the inputName field's value is being transferred with json.

This one works instead of above :

```
//This one is working
Input::merge(array('inputName' => 'manual Value something something here'));
```

Thanks in advance.

---UPDATE---

The problem is the value is being returned is null. I've written a test and solved it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fieldData = myModel::where('id', '=', '5')->first();

//change to this
$input_all = array_merge(Input::all(), array('inputName' => $fieldData->name));
$variableBag = $input_all;
```

I  hope this help, don't forget to check the result of `$fieldData` , is empty or not...

Answer (score 1):

Check your variable `$fieldData`.

And use instead `first` this: `firstOrFail`.